# Populating array of input fields as alternate fields using jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui datepicker in order to populate start and end dates for multiple events on the same page, the number of events is dynamic and I need to post day, month and year as separate fields, so I have something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="event[0].startDate" class="date"/>
<input type="hidden" name="event[0].startDate_day" class="startDate_day" />
<input type="hidden" name="event[0].startDate_month" class="startDate_month" />
<input type="hidden" name="event[0].startDate_year" class="startDate_year" />

<input type="text" name="event[0].endDate" class="date"/>
<input type="hidden" name="event[0].endDate_day" class="endDate_day" />
<input type="hidden" name="event[0].endDate_month" class="endDate_month" />
<input type="hidden" name="event[0].endDate_year" class="startDate_year" />

event[1]...
event[2]...
```

I started working on jQuery functionality and this is what I have so far, which will populate alternate fields for startDate by class, of course it will not do what I need because I need to populate by field name rather then class:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText,picker) {
        $('.startDate_month').val( dateText.split(/\//)[0] );
        $('.startDate_day').val( dateText.split(/\//)[1] );
        $('.startDate_year').val( dateText.split(/\//)[2] );
}});
```

I need help figuring out how can I get the name of the input field within datepicker function so the alternate field assignment done by that field name + _day, month, year so this function can work for all the events on the page, making function above look more like:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText,picker) {
        $('input[' + $name + '_month' + ']').val( dateText.split(/\//)[0] );
        $('input[' + $name + '_day' + ']').val( dateText.split(/\//)[1] );
        $('input[' + $name + '_year' + ']').val( dateText.split(/\//)[2] );
}});
```

Hope that makes sense :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities.

One is to give each item an ID as well (eg `<input id="event_0_endDate_day"…`, which is incidentally how Rails handles the naming conversion), and then select it with

```
$('#event_' + index + '_endDate_day')
```

The other is to use the property selection bits of Sparkle:

```
$('input["name"="event[' + index + '].startDate_day"])
```

The former would be greatly preferred, as the latter will perform much, much more poorly, but perhaps you have no other choice.

**edit**:

More specifically:

```
<input type="text" id="event_0_startDate" name="event[0].startDate" class="date"/>
<input type="hidden" id="event_0_startDate_day" name="event[0].startDate_day" class="startDate_day" />
<input type="hidden" id="event_0_startDate_month" name="event[0].startDate_month" class="startDate_month" />
<input type="hidden" id="event_0_startDate_year" name="event[0].startDate_year" class="startDate_year" />

<input type="text" id="event_0_endDate" name="event[0].endDate" class="date"/>
<input type="hidden" id="event_0_endDate_day" name="event[0].endDate_day" class="endDate_day" />
<input type="hidden" id="event_0_endDate_month" name="event[0].endDate_month" class="endDate_month" />
<input type="hidden" id="event_0_endDate_year" name="event[0].endDate_year" class="startDate_year" />
```

Then, you can do:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText,picker) {
        var prefix = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + prefix + '_month').val( dateText.split(/\//)[0] );
        $('#' + prefix + '_day').val( dateText.split(/\//)[1] );
        $('#' + prefix + '_year').val( dateText.split(/\//)[2] );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I can assign input ids the way you recommend but I still have two problems then. 1. How do I get the index and 2. This will only work for startDate and then i have to replicate the function for endDate. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To to add my comment to this problem. I used the id="" to assign a counter onto every  field so that I could successfully add a jQuery Date picker to each  field

Html

```
<input class="span2" onmouseover="autoCompleteMedicalHistory();"  type="text" id="MedicalHistoryOnset0" name="MedicalHistoryOnset[]" placeholder="Date of Diagnosis"/>
```

Javascript

```
var counter=1
var row=' <input class="span2" onmouseover="autoCompleteMedicalHistory();"  type="text" id="MedicalHistoryOnset'+counter+'" name="MedicalHistoryOnset[]" placeholder="Date of Diagnosis"/>"
```

Jquery Date Picker

```
jQuery("#MedicalHistoryOnset"+counter).datepicker({dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'});
```